# How to hide columns in a VBA named range?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm pretty new to VBA and I'm trying to hide some columns in workbooks.
I have to do it in VBA because the workbook is an Analysis for Office workbook, so I have to hide some columns that the final users don't have to see.
My problem is that I can't point to a specific letter of the columns, because, since the workbook is modifiable like a pivot with other dimensions in respect of the default ones with which it opens, if I point to a specific column in the code, it won't be the same when an user add new dimensions. So I have to find the column with its name ad hide it.

So for now I tried this:

```
Sub Hide_Columns()
'Dim Sourcecell As Range
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
'Set Sourcecell = Nothing
'Set Sourcecell = ThisSheet.Range("SapCrosstab1").Find("Colonna di calcolo", LookIn:=xlFormulas)
Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
Set ws = wb.Sheets("Demand Planning")

    wb.Sheets("Demand Planning").Range("Colonna di calcolo").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
End Sub
```

The problem here is that I'm having the

> "Run-time error 1004: Application-defined or object-defined error"

and I don't know how to fix it.
I commented that 3 lines because I'm not so sure they could help.

Comment: This doesn't answer your question but you set an object reference: `Set ws = wb.Sheets("Demand Planning")`, so this line `wb.Sheets("Demand Planning").Range("Colonna di calcolo").EntireColumn.Hidden = True` could instead be `ws.Range("Colonna di calcolo").EntireColumn.Hidden = True`. Note that `Range("Colonna di calcolo")` will not return a range that contains "Colonna di calcolo", it will return a range whose name is "Colonna di calcolo" -- and if there isn't a range with that name, you'll get an error (see FunThomas' answer below).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current attempt fails because `Range("Colonna di calcolo")` will not search for a column with that header. Instead, it want to access a *Named Range* with that name, and if you don't define this, it will throw exactly this error 1004.

I think your attempt with `SourceCell` was not bad - issue a Find command and hide the `EntireColumn` of the found cell. Your mistake was that there is no object `ThisSheet`. There are objects `ThisWorkbook` which refers to the entire workbook where the code is stored, or `ActiveWorkbook` which is the Workbook that is currently shown (not necessarily the workbook where the macro is stored).

You can solve your issue either by defining a Named Range for the column - in that case your code should work.
Or change the code to something like

```
Dim ws as Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Demand Planning")

Dim Sourcecell as Range
Set Sourcecell = ws.Range("1:1").Find("Colonna di calcolo", LookIn:=xlFormulas)
If Not Sourcecell Is Nothing Then
    Sourcecell.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
End If
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!
I tried your code and even if it doesn't give any error, the column still remains unhide, I don't know why...

Comment: Have you tried to debug it (execute it step by step)?

Comment: Yes, but the only thing it says it's if I position the cursor over Sourcecell.EntireColumn.Hidden = True and it says: "Object variable or With block variable not set"

Comment: In that case, the `Find` didn't find anything. Is the seacth string correct? Is the Column header in row 1? Is the worksheet the corrent one?

Comment: Uh, I found the error, my mistake!
In effect, the header is in line 23, I modified and now it works! Thank you very much for your help!
Kudos to you!